# Multi-column CSS list absolute positioned

Tags: css, safari

I've got a multi-column list within an absolute positioned div using `column-count`:

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
}

ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>ListItem1</li>
        <li>ListItem2</li>
        <li>ListItem3</li>
        <li>ListItem4</li>
        <li>ListItem5</li>
        <li>ListItem6</li>
        <li>ListItem7</li>
        <li>ListItem8</li>
        <li>ListItem9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This works fine in all major browsers, however in Safari  7 the div doesnt expand to the width of the double column list, and remains the same width as if it was a single column list:

[image: Safari 7 Layout]

Is there something I'm missing, am I misusing the column-count property or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You are using it fine, it's a documented bug in Safari 5.1+, and is connected to the absolute positioning. If you change the position of the div to relative, not absolute, it works.